# Adding research assistanship leading to book to CV

Tags: resume

I was research assistant of a Professor for two years. During that time, I helped him with the production of a book. This involved bibliographic research, dataset construction, graphs and table production, and general text revision and editing. He then published the book, acknowledging me on it.

How should I add this into my CV? What is the precise category? Publications? What is the precise tag for it? Collaboration?

Comment: Don't worry about being precise. Just be clear.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned your title of Research Assistant already. Put this under Work Experience and list out your duties as you have done here. I would also include which book you helped publish. This could also fall in publication, but it's tacky if you only have this one publication.